# Ejecutar Script sin invalidar la propiedad required en un documento HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, validación

Estoy ejecutando un script referenciado en un documento HTML y todo funciona muy bien, excepto la validación de los inputs en el formulario

Estoy intentando algo así:

```
<!--Documento index.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-co">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Documento Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>  
<form name="formulario" id="form1" autocomplete="off">
        <label>Valor</label>
        <input type="text" id="valor" placeholder="Digita un valor" required/>
        <input type="submit" id="subcapturar" value="Capturar">
 </form>
 <div id="mensaje"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>  
 </body>
 </html>
```

El código JS:

```
 //Documento main.js
 $("#subcapturar").click(function(event){
     var mivalor=$("#valor").val();
     $("#mensaje").text("El valor capturado fue :" + mivalor);
     event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Este script funciona bien, el problema esta en que el envio se hace sin realizar la validación required del input id=valor.

Intente cambiando el evento en JS

```
 $("#form1").submit(function(event){
    var mivalor=$("#valor").val();
    $("#mensaje").text("El valor capturado fue :" + mivalor);
});
```

Más no funciono. ¿Alguien tiene una solución?

No veo que este fallando en mi lògica
Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar el método `preventDefault()`, y luego que se efectúe la validación de ser necesario envías el formulario con el método `submit()`.

Ejemplo:

```js
//Documento main.js
function validar() {

 event.preventDefault();    // previene que el formulario sea enviado

 var mivalor=$("#valor").val();
 $("#mensaje").text("El valor capturado fue :" + mivalor);

 // aquí colocas el envío del formulario formName.submit() (de ser necesario)
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="formulario" id="form1" autocomplete="off" onSubmit="validar()">
        <label>Valor</label>
        <input type="text" id="valor" placeholder="Digita un valor" required/>
        <input type="submit" id="subcapturar" value="Capturar">
 </form>
 <div id="mensaje"></div>
```

Comment: Excelente, sirvio a la perfección. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: que bueno! me alegra verte ayudado y recuerda puntuar la respuesta que mas se adecue a tus requerimientos, Saludos!! ;)...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que esta sucediendo es que en ningún momento se esta invocando la escucha de tu botón. Para esto necesitas cambiar tu main.js a algo asi:

```
$(function() {
    $("#subcapturar").click(function(event){
        var mivalor=$("#valor").val();
        $("#mensaje").text("El valor capturado fue :" + mivalor);
    });
});
```

De esta manera funcionará, ya lo probé.

Una cosa más, como tu formulario de tu html no especificaste action, entonces no te dejará leer tu mensaje. Si quieres poder leer el mensaje tu html podria quedar así:

```
<!--Documento index.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-co">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Documento Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>  
<form name="formulario" id="form1" autocomplete="off" action="#">
        <label>Valor</label>
        <input type="text" id="valor" placeholder="Digita un valor" required/>
        <input type="submit" id="subcapturar" value="Capturar">
 </form>
 <div id="mensaje"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Un saludo y espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, probé esta solución en mi proyecto, y funciono, más le agregue un event.preventDefault() para mostrar el resultado en la etiqueta div id=mensaje. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda